# Stack and Queue Methods

Tags: stack, queue

This is an excerpt from a book called "Professional Javascript for Web Developers".

It says :

*"One of the interesting things about ECMAScript arrays is that they provide a method to make an array behave like other data structures. An array object can act just like a stack, which is one of a group of data structures **that restrict the insertion and removal of items.** A stack is referred to as a last-in-first-out (LIFO) structure, meaning that **the most recently added item is the first one removed.***

I am confused here. Is a stack a restricted method for insertion and removal or items, or not? It says "a group of data structures that restrict the insertion and removal of items." --> That "restricts". And then it says just the opposite : "A stack is referred to as a last-in-first-out (LIFO) structure, meaning that the most recently added item is the first one removed."

And then, it occurs the same about Queue Methods:

*Just as stacks restrict access in a LIFO data structure, queues restrict access in a first-in-first-out (FIFO) data structure. A queue adds items to the end of a list and retrieves items from the front of the list*

Again, it says it restricts access, and then it says that is "adds and retrieves" items..

I am crazy, or this is absolutely contradictory?

Answer (score 0):

A stack is a last-in-first-out (LIFO) structure while a queue is a first-in-first-out (FIFO) structure. Both of them are restricted in the order of insertion and removal of items. By that it means that for stack, you can only remove the item you pushed last; while for queue, you can only remove the items in the order you pushed them. If you insert 1, 2, 3 in a stack, they can only be removed in opposite order - 3, 2, 1. Think of this as stacking plates on top of each other. Next for queue, if you insert 1, 2, 3, you can only remove them in the order 1, 2, 3. You can think of queues as the waiting 'queue' in offices, bus stops and other place, people get into and get out of the queue in same order.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I understood the difference between LIFO and FIFO, but I got confused specifically on this sentence : 
'...that restrict the insertion and removal of items.".

So, neither of both restrict the insertion and removal. They restrict THE ORDER of insertion and removal. right ?

Comment: Well, it meant same thing, restricting the ORDER of insertion and removal. Also, you can't insert if the Stack of Queue is already full.